# creating new record in target schema only for distinct vales from source schema

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a source schema and a target schema. My aim is to create a new record in source message while only a new values comes from a source schema element.

source schema:

```
<Employees>
   <Employee>
       <Full Name>
```

Target Schema:

```
<Users>
  <User>
    <New Name>
```

If I provide input

```
<Employees>  
    <Employee>
      <ABC>
      <ABC>
      <XYZ>
      <XYZ>
```

In output message there should only be two messages

```
<Users>
    <User>
       <ABC>
       <XYZ>
```

As looping functoid will take each value from the input, I don't think it's useful. 
How can I achieve it by other means?

Comment: Have you tried a search for "'biztalk map distinct values" e.g geekswithblogs.net/MainaD/archive/2007/10/29/116441.aspx  That has examples for both using Functoids and XSLT

Comment: Also are you wanting distinct values or element names?  Usually you would not have data as element names.  So can you give some complete and accurate examples?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I tried searching but couldn't reach the article. Thanks you so much!!     You saved the day!! Many thanks!!